# Deobfuscate PHP code (recursive)

Tags: php, deobfuscation

I want to deobfuscate this PHP, is a PHP shell, and I have tried to deobfuscate it without success.

Is it possible to achive it? If so, I would appreciate your help. This is the PHP: http://pastebin.com/v3JKLRi2

Comment: Why¿? The point is to know where how to deobfuscate not only for this specific code

Comment: This could be a good question if you can bring a code sample into the question. The block of "code" in the pasteboard is rather unwieldy and lengthy to paste into the question, but good questions must have the code in the body of the question itself. Links break, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes you are right, links break... I couldn't break the code into small pieces because would be useless I think. I don't know if I deserve recieving minus points for something I'm sure it's not only me who want to solve this but... people are the one rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run it (ideally in a sandbox or a vm for safety). It won't work on PHP > 5 though as `preg_replace()` has been changed.

[See here](http://3v4l.org/jNlVi#v5438) for the plain code.

I wouldn't advise using the plain code though unless you are sure what it does. I haven't read it.

Comment: For future readers, "just run it" is probably not OK in general! Often this kind of code is malicious.

Comment: @halfer Thats why I used a sandbox and not my PC :)

Comment: Hey ! by "just run it" you mean the button "eval" right¿? If the input is too large, how to deal with it? As for instance: http://pastebin.com/dDSWFMad
Thank you very much really!